# AngularJs screen refreshing on poll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, settimeout, polling

I have a list of devices that I am needing regular updates from to see what they are displaying. So, I set the poll interval to 15,000ms. Everytime the list gets updated the list will flicker quickly then move me back to the top of the list. Is there anyway to prevent it from moving the user back to the top of the list but still poll the devices?

> Poller:

```
 let deviceCurrentRequestsFormatter = function (value: any, row: any, index: number) {
                let __this = this;
                let requests = $tcore.utilityTIS.filterBySiteIdIntId(_this.deviceCurrentRequestsList, row.SiteId, row.IntId);
                if (requests && requests.length) {
                    let sources = _.find(requests, function (request) {
                        return request.SourceType === __this.field;
                    });
                    if (sources && sources.Enabled)
                        return "<i class=\"fa fa-check tc-check-color\"></i>";
                }
                return "";
            };

            this.pollInterval = setInterval(function () {
                _this.getDeviceBrowserList();
                console.log("%c This is polling: ", "background: red; color: yellow; font-size: x-large")
            }, 15000);


            setTimeout(function () {
                _this.getDeviceBrowserList();
            }, 1000);
        }
```

> What the poll is looking at:

```
 private getDeviceBrowserList() {
            let _this = this;
            this.widgetObject.parentEntity.getDeviceBrowserList().then(function (message: any) {
                if (message) {
                    _this.deviceBrowserList = message.Device;
                    _this.deviceTypeList = message.DeviceType;
                    _this.deviceCurrentRequestsList = message.DeviceCurrentRequests;

                    if (_.isUndefined(_this.pageSize)) {
                        _this.pageSize = 10;
                    }

                    _this.checkPrivilegeAccess(0, _this.pageSize).then(function() {
                        _this.buildDeviceBrowserListTable(message.Device, message.DeviceType, message.DeviceCurrentRequests);

                        _this.widgetObject.parentEntity.getFonts().then(function (data: any) {
                            $tcore.utilityTCS.showOrHideProgres(false);
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's your dom rendering situation here so:

1. If you're using an ngRepeat directive you can use track by (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates) to prevent the unneeded creating and removing of elements.
2. If buildDeviceBrowserListTable builds the html by itself you need to change it so it will update elements if they already exist - i.e change their content without removing and recreating elements.

These two solutions will fix the flickering and the scrolling

Comment: Thank you I will try making your changes and update when done